# App Inventor, add items to list and view

Tags: android, list, app-inventor, viewer

I've been searching and watching tons of youtube videos, but i really can't figure this out.

i have a drop-down menu, with some items in it. The user have to pick an item and this item should be stored in the display screen. 
Right now i have it so the user can pick an item from drop-down menu in screen1 and add to screen2. 
But if i want to add another item, the itemViewer delete the first item and replace it with the new one.

So what i want, is to add more items from screen 1 to screen 2, without it replace the other one.

and here is my code
**Screen1**
[image]
**Screen2**
[image]

Comment: *and here is my code as image* - Nope, don't do that. We hate it. Post code as code please

Comment: yeah sure i understand that, but as App inventar is in blocks language i'm not sure how i could do that.

Answer (score 0):

After coming back to Screen1, you have to read the stored list again from `TinyDB` and assign it your variable `listOfItems` before adding new items (else you start again with an empty list).

See also the [TinyDB tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/stevozip/home/AI2/tinydb) by Stephen and the [recommended method of switching screens](https://puravidaapps.com/manager.php)